# Is there a name for the tone of voice that modern British newsreaders use when announcing serious subjects?

Tags: single-word-requests, accent

This question stems from pure idle curiosity. It seems to me that British newsreaders use a special accent, especially when reading out the headlines or introducing a particularly serious story. Perhaps it would be more properly termed a tone of voice rather than an accent, but in either case I've never known anyone to speak in that way in any other situation.

I'm not referring to [recieved pronunciaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation), but to something much more specific that seems to be only used for news and not other announcements. Similarly, I'm not referring to the [mid-Atlantic accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Atlantic_accent), which also seems to be mostly associated with news readers but is no longer in use. The voice/accent I'm referring to combines a kind of exaggerated seriousness with perhaps a lower pitch of voice than usual. It's difficult to describe but anyone who lives in the UK should be familiar with it. Does it have a name?

Edit: an exaggerated example can be found in this [classic parody clip from The Day Today](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IEwBrJzhlg). Most of the characters use their normal voices at first, but once the situation changes around 2 minutes in, all the broadcasters start using the special "serious" voice that I'm asking about.

Comment: Uh… which newsreaders, please?

Two generations ago, pretty-much every British newsreader used the same accent.

Today, it seems to depend where they were born and there is certainly no  single accent that modern British newsreaders use, nor anything like one.

Comment: I did my best to explain it in the question. Please read it completely and let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Sorry, Nathaniel. I've only been listening for 60 years.

British newsreaders used to speak with one voice, as it were, but for a least a generation, they haven't. Their diversity sounds to be getting greater, too.

Could you find someone else who's heard this… or could you name a few culprits? Say four or five?

Comment: I did mention RP in the question, and specifically noted that it's not what I was talking about. The word "accent" might be a red herring. I'm talking about the voice they put on when reading the headlines or introducing a particularly serious story. I would say most newsreaders do it, regardless of their accent. It might be marginally less exaggerated now than it was about 5-10 years ago.

Comment: Nathaniel, I noticed that you mentioned RP in the question and I mentioned I've only been listening for 60 years and I not only haven't heard what you describe; I have heard something very different; almost opposite.

Would you rather *Yes it is… No it isn't* or could you name a few culprits? Say four or five? Most British newsreaders are available for comparison on catch-up… no argument…

Comment: This is a parody but might help get the point across. He uses something close to his normal voice when speaking to camera but puts on the "serious" voice for the voiceovers. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHun58mz3vI (Even though it's a parody the difference isn't very strong, but it's there. If I can find a more obvious example I'll post it.)

Comment: Another parody but a much better example. The voice is used by virtually all characters, starting at about 2 minutes in. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IEwBrJzhlg

Comment: It's more to do with tone of voice and how newsreaders punctuate their speech, I enjoyed the first YT video immensely, thank you for posting. The 2nd YTV is less entertaining, I think the comedian is imitating either Jeremy Paxman or Andrew Marr but I'm not sure as I don't watch that much British news in Italy (no satellite dish).

Comment: Two things could be colouring your hearing…

I've heard that newsreaders are taught to speak about 112 words a minute; unnatural enough to require concentration. Both the pacing and the distraction might change their intonation, or some other vocal characteristic.

Further almost no-one… including newsreaders, actors and public speakers, can read anything in a normal speaking voice. Try… it's almost impossible. The only person I've ever known to do it is Donald Trump, which skill doubtless contributes to his popularity because it makes him sound like the world's only sincere politician.

Comment: "*Serious* voice" as in the last paragraph of the question, works very well.  To my ear it's slightly lower in pitch, slightly slower, and enunciated very clearly.  The opposite effect is seen in "And finally.." items, which are usually lighter in tone.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, these days there are nearly as many news presenters with regional - particularly Scottish - accents as those using RP, which is the dominant form.

Regional accents are often deemed to be "from somewhere real" and so appparently are judged to have integrity. RP is respected and seen as educated, but doesn't have a specific area of origin tbat people can relate to; at best it's the South East of England accent.

There are some interesting stats in this report about how various British accents are perceived: 1) how friendly; 2) how intelligent; 3) how trustworthy
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2433201/Scousers-intelligent-trustworthy-accent--Devonians-friendliest.html

50 years ago, there was a predominance of the cut-glass upper-class accent on the BBC, the way the queen speaks. But that has almost completely gone now, and old clips with presenters speaking in that way are hilarious today, for the deference to the aristocracy and royals they represent.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'portentous'springs to mind.